# What does "melanistic phase" mean in regards to black jaguars?

Tags: genetics, zoology

From [Black Jaguars in Belize?: A survey of melanism in the jaguar, panthera onca](http://biological-diversity.info/Black_Jaguar.htm) by John R. Meyer:

> There occurs in jaguars, as well as in leopards (Panthera pardus), a melanistic phase which has been much sought by zoos for exhibition purposes. This color phase was relatively difficult to acquire until the 1970's, by which time a few zoos, among them the Jacksonville Zoo, had begun to breed them regularly.

And likewise on the Wikipedia page for [Black Panther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_panther):

> This "black cougar" was most likely a margay or ocelot, which are under 18 kg (40 lb) in weight, live in trees, and do have melanistic phases.

I don't understand this term "melanistic phase", which makes it sound like the jaguar has a period of time in which it is black.  However, it looks like it means something else, i.e., along the lines of [What does phasing mean?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/9326/5611), but I don't really understand that.

What does "melanistic phase" mean in regards to black jaguars?

Comment: I think it is coming from color phase (see meaning 2: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color%20phase or meaning 1: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/color-phase)

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "phase" means the same thing as "color phase". Here's [the definition from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/color%20phase):

> 1: a seasonally variant pelage color
>   2: (a) a genetic variant manifested by the occurrence of a skin or pelage color unlike the wild type of the animal group in which it appears (b) an individual marked by such a variant

So it sounds as if "phase" originated in the case of animals that spent a season with a particular pelage (meaning "fur, hair or wool"), such as the [snowshoe hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowshoe_hare), which is brown in summer and turns white in winter, and the term then began to be used for animals that might be a different color from other individuals of that species. If the alternate color was caused by a recessive allele, most offspring of that individual would have the wildtype color unless bred with another double-recessive individual, and alternate offspring might spontaneously be born to wildtype heterozygous individuals, so pre-Mendel biologists might have seen it as a "phase" between wildtype generations.

As you can see from the illustrations on the snowshoe hare Wikipedia article, "morph" is much more commonly used today for this kind of visible variation within a species. Wikipedia has a fuller description of the [nomenclature of this and related terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(biology)#Nomenclature).